# Should I let non-members add comment to a post?

Tags: security, anonymous

As long as it's SQL injection proof, would it be alright for me to let non-members add comments to a post and give the Author the ability to delete them?

Comment: If it's alright for you is up to you decide. Is it alright for me to wear a t-shirt?

Comment: You'll also want to HTML-escape the comments when you fetch them from the database before you display them, otherwise you're open to XSS.

Comment: But... it sort of depends what other things you have in place. Do you have a good rate-limiting scheme set up so a user can't just fill your hard drive with randomly-generated comments? Do you have a system in place to automatically ban users / IP addresses who seem to be abusive? Do you have a limit on the number / number of kilobytes of comments loaded per page (so someone can't fill a page with comments, making the page take forever to load / making it easy to DoS you by making a lot of requests for that page)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Before you do it, consider the following questions

(*and any other questions specific to your project that may spring to mind*)

- **Do you have a good rate-limiting scheme** set up so a user can't just fill your hard drive with randomly-generated comments?
- **Do you have a system in place to automatically ban users / IP addresses** who seem to be abusive? Do you have a limit on the number / number of kilobytes of comments loaded per page (so someone can't fill a page with comments, making the page take forever to load / making it easy to DoS you by making a lot of requests for that page)?
- **Is it possible to fold comments out of sight** on the webpage so users can easily hide spammy comments they'd rather not see?
- **Is it possible for legitimate users to report spammy comments?**

These are all issues that apply to full members, of course. But it also matters for anonymous users, and since anonymous posting is low-hanging fruit, a botmaster would be more likely to target that. The main thing is simply to consider "If I were a skilled programmer who hated this website, or wanted to make money from advertising on it, and I have a small botnet, what is the worst thing I could do to this website using anonymous comments given the resources I have?" And that's a tough question, which depends a great deal on what other stuff you have in place.

### If you do it, here are a few pointers:

- **HTML-escape the comments** when you fetch them from the database before you display them, otherwise you're open to XSS.
- **Make sure you never run any eval-like function on the input** the user gives you (this includes printf; to do something like that you'd want to stick with `printf("%s", userStr);`, so printf doesn't directly try to interpret `userStr`. If you care about why that's an issue, google for Aleph One's seminal paper on stack smashing),
- **Never rely on the size of the input** to fall within a specific range (even if you check this in Javascript; in fact, especially if you try to ensure this in Javascript) and
- **Never trust anything about the content will be true** (make no assumptions about character encoding, for example. Remember, a malicious user won't need to use a browser; they can craft their calls however they want).
- **Default to paranoia** If someone posts 20 comments in a minute, ban them from commenting for a while. If they keep doing that, ban their IP. If they're a real person, and they care, they'll ask you to undo it. Plus, if they're a real person, and they have a history of posting 20 comments a minute, chances are pretty good those comments would be improved by some time under the banhammer; no one's **that** witty.

Comment: All great points that I will keep in mind. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @user3753805 So, as part of considering adding anonymous comments to my site, I asked [this question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67584/how-much-text-does-the-average-person-generate-per-day), and reached a conclusion (I though might be useful to have) about rate limiting implementation. Hopefully that'll also help. [As usual, math came to the rescue.](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Better_Off_Ted#The_Impertence_of_Communicationizing_.5B2.08.5D)

Answer (score 0):

Typically this kind of question depends on the type of community, as well as the control you give your authors. Definitely implement safety and a verification system (eg CAPTCHA), but this is something you'll have to gauge over time more often than not. If users are being well-behaved, then it's fine. If they start spamming every post they get their hands on, then it's probably time a feature like that should just go away.